# Rails 3 on dreamhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

I'd like to deploy a small Rails 3 app on dreamhost (just for testing purposes, nothing serious) and I am wondering if anyone has done it already... Please choose one of the following:

1. I did it and it's super easy, here's how: ...
2. Though I didn't try it, it should be easy, here's how: ...
3. It's quite complicated, but this should get you started: ....
4. NO WAI!!!1!one!1 Set it up on slicehost or another non-shared hosting or you'll die a painful death trying to force it on DH

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think it heavily depends on Dreamhost installing the gems for you, and allowing access to them through the shared environment. You could contact their support department for more information on if and when they plan on deploying Rails 3 to their shared servers.

On the other hand, you *could* do what your fourth option implies and just go ahead and get a slice somewhere (doesn't necessarily need to be with SliceHost; you could deploy cheaply with Heroku) which allows you to deploy your own gems.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Heroku is a nice idea - I am curious when/how they are going to support Rails 3. Will peek around, thanks!

Comment: heroku is super expensive compared to anyone else out there

Comment: see my answer below, I got this working without issue using rvm on dreamhost with fastcgi

Answer (score 9):

You can do this but it requires advanced sysadm skills.

In order to use Rails 3 on DreamHost you need to:

- install Ruby 1.8.7
- install RubyGems
- install Rails 3

all in your own home directory because you don't have privileges to install everything elsewhere.

Also, this isn't guarantee to work with the existing Dreamhost Passenger configuration.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I suspected something like this, which is option 4 for me :-)

Comment: With rvm, this isn't very difficult

Answer (score 6):

Here are some fresh instructions:

http://blog.joeygeiger.com/2010/05/17/i-beat-dreamhost-how-to-really-get-rails-3-bundler-and-dreamhost-working/

Comment: Still too many dependencies that need to be updated on DreamHost's side. http://blog.joeygeiger.com/2010/08/06/dreamhost-you-win-or-lose-really/

Answer (score 2):

I just received an email from dreamhost.  I emailed them about 2 months ago regarding rails 3.0, they are starting to push it onto their servers as we speak.  Assuming things work out, rails 3 should be supported within the month.

Answer (score 1):

The dreamhost machine I have allocated space on, pisces, appears to have upgraded to Rails 3.0.3 yesterday.  I only noticed because a Redmine instance broke horribly :(

Answer (score 1):

As of today, here are what's my dreamhost machine:

```
    $ rails -v
    Rails 3.0.3

    $ ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]

    $ gem list

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    actionpack (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    actionwebservice (1.2.6, 1.2.3)
    activemodel (3.0.3)
    activerecord (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    activeresource (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    acts_as_taggable (2.0.2, 1.0.4)
    ajax_scaffold_generator (3.1.11, 2.2.1)
    archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2, 0.5.1)
    arel (2.0.4)
    auth_generator (2.0.1, 1.5.3)
    Bloglines4R (0.1.0)
    BlueCloth (1.0.0)
    builder (2.1.2, 2.0.0)
    bundler (1.0.7)
    camping (1.5.180, 1.5)
    capistrano (2.5.1, 2.1.0, 1.4.1)
    classifier (1.3.1)
    cmdparse (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
    curb (0.1.4)
    daemons (1.0.10, 1.0.9)
    dbd-mysql (0.4.3)
    dbi (0.4.3)
    deprecated (2.0.1)
    erubis (2.6.6)
    eventmachine (0.12.10, 0.12.8)
    facets (2.2.1, 1.8.54)
    fastthread (1.0.7, 1.0.1)
    feedtools (0.2.29, 0.2.28)
    ferret (0.11.6, 0.11.4)
    flickr (1.0.2)
    gd2 (1.1.1, 1.1)
    gen (0.41.0)
    geoip (0.6.1)
    gettext (1.90.0)
    glue (0.41.0)
    gnuplot (2.2)
    gravtastic (2.0.0)
    gruff (0.3.1)
    haml (2.0.3)
    hoe (1.5.1)
    hpricot (0.6)
    htmltools (1.10)
    i18n (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
    localization_generator (1.0.8)
    login_generator (1.2.2)
    madeleine (0.7.3)
    mail (2.2.15)
    markaby (0.5)
    mechanize (0.7.6)
    metaid (1.0)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mini_magick (1.2.3)
    mysql (2.7)
    needle (1.3.0)
    net-sftp (1.1.1)
    net-ssh (2.0.23, 1.1.2)
    nitro (0.41.0)
    nokogiri (1.4.4)
    og (0.41.0)
    oniguruma (1.1.0)
    packet (0.1.14)
    PageTemplate (2.2.0)
    ParseTree (2.1.1)
    payment (1.0.1)
    pdf-writer (1.1.8)
    podcast (0.0.4)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
    rack-mount (0.6.13)
    rack-test (0.5.6)
    radiant (0.6.9)
    rails (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.2)
    railties (3.0.3)
    rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3, 0.8.2)
    RedCloth (3.0.4)
    rfacebook (0.9.8)
    rmagick (1.15.14)
    rspec (1.1.3)
    ruby-breakpoint (0.5.1)
    ruby-debug (0.10.0)
    ruby-openid (2.1.7)
    ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
    ruby_odeum (0.4.1)
    rubyforge (0.4.5)
    RubyInline (3.6.7)
    rubypants (0.2.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.1)
    ruport (1.6.0)
    ruport-util (0.14.0)
    ruwiki (0.9.3)
    salted_login_generator (2.0.2)
    shipping (1.5.1)
    SimpleSearch (0.5.0)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.2.1)
    stemmer (1.0.1)
    switchtower (1.0.1)
    syntax (1.0.0)
    tagtools (0.0.3)
    thor (0.14.6, 0.14.4)
    tidy (1.1.2)
    treetop (1.4.9)
    tzinfo (0.3.23)
    unicode (0.1)
    uuidtools (1.0.3)
    webgen (0.4.7)
    wee (0.10.0)
    xhtmldiff (1.0.0)
    xml-simple (1.0.11)
    ym4r (0.6.1)
    youtube-g (0.4.9.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Passenger documentation: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#bundler_support

Create a file **config/setup_load_paths.rb** in your app and add this line:

```
$: << "<path-where-bundler-gem-was-installed>/lib"
```

I unpacked bundler gem in vendor/bundle path with this command:

```
gem unpack bundler --target=vendor/bundle
```

And the others gems with:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

This should work with Dreamhost and Passenger >= 2.2.14

Comment: too bad Dreamhost shared servers are still stuck on Passenger 2.2.9

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using rvm and fastcgi

My .htaccess file looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L] 

ErrorDocument 500 "Rails application failed to start properly for your rails app"
```

And my dispatch.fcgi looked like (note you need to fill in ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/<MY_HOME_DIR>/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p0@awesome

require 'rubygems'
require 'fcgi'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production' 
#ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'


# Set GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME ("user" is your dreamhost user)
ENV['GEM_HOME'] ||= '/home/<MY_HOMEDIR>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@awesome'
ENV['GEM_PATH'] ||= '/home/<MY_HOMEDIR>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@awesome:/home/<MY_HOMEDIR>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global'
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment')

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
   @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
   env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
   parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
   env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
   env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
   @app.call(env)
 end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(Imjustsayin::Application)
```