# no such file to load -- bundler with rails app using apache passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

i am using apache passenger to run rails app on local development.i have successfully install apache passenger,mysql and all related stuff.here is my appache/httpd.conf file code

```
     LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
     PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
     PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8

  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.local
    DocumentRoot "/home/kashif/sunsspot_search/public"
    RailsEnv development

   <directory "/home/kashif/sunsspot_search/public">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
   </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i start apache using this command
                  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

then this message come

```
           [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

when i visit foo.local/posts
then i have this error

```
         no such file to load -- bundler
```

please help.why this error occur and also see my apache configuration are correct?

Thanks

Comment: One thing I noticed "directory" should be capitalized,  your indentions are off on your "Order allow" statements.

Comment: For the no such file to load error check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570522/no-such-file-to-load-bundler-error-for-rails-3