# Dreamhost: two different Ruby versions and gemsets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, dreamhost

I am using dreamhost shared server.  I get this error message, I do not understand what these error means. Does this shows passenger uses dreamhost default ruby 1.8 instead of my local 1.9.3? These error messages shows passesnger is using usr/lib/ instead of my home folders. Thanks in advance.

```
In config/environmnet.rb:
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
RailsMichaelcunnaneCom::Application.initialize!
```

.

```
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  in `exit'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  
2   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `gem_original_require'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `require'
4   /home/miccun2/rails.michaelcunnane.com/config/boot.rb   6   
5   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
7   /home/miccun2/rails.michaelcunnane.com/config/application.rb    1   
8   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
10  /home/miccun2/rails.michaelcunnane.com/config/environment.rb    2   
11  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
13  config.ru   3   
14  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `instance_eval'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `initialize'
16  config.ru   1   in `new'
17  config.ru   1
```

Ruby version:

```
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ which ruby
/home/miccun2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
```

Rails version & up and running

```
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ which rails
/home/miccun2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p194 :001 > exit
```

RVM version and gemset selection

```
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /home/miccun2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
   rails_michaelcunnane_com

miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ rvm gemset use rails_michaelcunnane_com --default
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails_michaelcunnane_com
```

Bundle Show after Bundle installation

```
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.3)
  * actionpack (3.2.3)
  * activemodel (3.2.3)
  * activerecord (3.2.3)
  * activeresource (3.2.3)
  * activesupport (3.2.3)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.3)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.3.2)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.3)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.1)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.18)
  * multi_json (1.3.4)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.3)
  * railties (3.2.3)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * sass (3.1.17)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.6)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.4)
miccun2@oslo:~/rails.michaelcunnane.com$
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I deployed a Rails 3 application Dreamhost didn't offer 1.9.2. So my app used default 1.8.7. I think they still don't offer 1.9.2.

I didn't use RVM, I wanted that at first but I think it is too much of a hassle. Dreamhost Wiki has information but it was unsupported. So no help from Dreamhost if things go wrong. No help also when using your own 1.9.2.

On my laptop I use RVM of course but on Dreamhost PS just Dreamhost Ruby 1.8.7. The only thing I needed to change to get my Passenger Rails 3 app working was .gemrc in home directory which only has

```
gemhome: /home/myuser/.gems/
gempath:
- /home/myuser/.gems/
```

Comment: I think I used/read this article and found it useful http://grigio.org/finally_rails_3_dreamhost_tips_n_fail. And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250247/rails-3-on-dreamhost